# Java NIO Simple Web Server: How to handle very large read?

Tags: java, nio

In all examples of NIO server code, I have seen code like:

```
private void read(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    ...
    socketChannel.read(readBuffer)
    ...
    workerThread.processData(readBuffer.array())
```

How would you handle the case where the data being read is very large (say a gigabyte file being uploaded which should be streamed directly into a file - not stored in memory)?

Thank you

Comment: Process the data in chunks. It's basically the same way you do it with "old" IO.

Comment: You won't get a single large read. You won't read anything larger than the socket receive buffer. Certainly not a gigabyte.

Answer (score 0):

Use SplitCap
http://www.netresec.com/?page=SplitCap 
You can split it in smaller pieces.